# How can I delete stopwords from a column in a df?

Tags: python, dataframe

I've been trying to delete the stopwords from a column in a df, but I'm having trouble doing it.

```
discografia["SSW"] = [word for word in discografia.CANCIONES if not word in stopwords.words('spanish')]
```

But in the new column I just get the same words as in the column "CANCIONES". What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: what is the type of `stopwords.words('spanish')` and the type of `discografia.CANCIONES`

Comment: @gold_cy `stopwords.words('spanish')` is a list and `discografia.CANCIONES` is a column from a df

Comment: @gold_cy  inside each row of `discografia.CANCIONES` there are lists

Comment: so each row of the data frame is a list?

Answer (score 0):

We can use [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) in conjunction with grouping by the original index to assign back to the original DataFrame.

```
stopwords = ["buzz"]
df = pd.DataFrame({"CANCIONES": [["fizz", "buzz", "foo"], ["baz", "buzz"]]})

words = r".|".join(stopwords)

exploded = df.explode("CANCIONES")
print(exploded)

  CANCIONES
0      fizz
0      buzz
0       foo
1       baz
1      buzz

df["SSW"] = exploded.loc[~exploded.CANCIONES.str.contains(words)].reset_index().groupby(
    "index", as_index=False
).agg({"CANCIONES": list}).CANCIONES

print(df)
           CANCIONES          SSW
0  [fizz, buzz, foo]  [fizz, foo]
1        [baz, buzz]        [baz]
```